# Create List with dropdown button which expands the list & then disappear

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, widget

as in whatsapp android version, user details screen contains a section of mutual groups which when greater than 3, automatically places a button to expand the list. I want to add this feature to my app. Lets have a look at image as well.

[image: Like_that]

I have tried ConstrainedBox which only adds scrolling behaiour but not putting a button at last.

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/expandable

Comment: Thanks for your response. i want to know is there any other way to do this except a package?

Answer (score 1):

You can use ListView builder for it, first take an Column widget then in children [Text("Create Groups with __"),Container- ( Listview.builder), ElevatedButton], now add condition that if listview have item count less then 3 then Elevated button will disappear, and if listview have itemcount more than 3 then elevated button will show, and when user press the Elevated button then listview will expand.  here you have to one more thing, as you know listview needs some fixed height so we use container above the listview with fixed height. now you have to create an logic which changes the height of container as user press the Elevated button,

i hope its help you, let me know whenever you stucks